# Excel VBA - Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I need help. The below code is written to add to column data and store in another column. When I execute the code it says subscript out of range in for loop where it adds to array values.

Kindly give an advice.

Thanks

```
Sub test()

    Dim W1, W2, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5 As Double
    Dim i, j, T As Integer
    Dim myRange As Double
    Dim Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant, Arr3 As Variant

    myRange1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("M15", "M30")
    myRange2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("N15", "N30")
    R1 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange1)
    R2 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange2)
    R3 = (R1 + R2)
    R4 = (R1 / R3) * 100
    R5 = (R2 / R3) * 100
    Range("M31") = R4
    Range("N31") = R5
    Arr1 = Range("M15:M30").Value
    Arr2 = Range("N15:N30").Value

    For i = LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr1)
        Arr3(i) = Arr1(i) + Arr2(i)
    Next

    T = 16
    For j = 1 To T
        Range("M" & 33 + j).Cells = Arr3
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Arr3 is never 
The error is caused because `Arr3` was never initialized as an array.  `Arr1(i)` will also throw an error because `Arr1` is a 2 dimensional array; use `Arr1(i, 1)` instead.

```
ReDim Arr3(LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr1))
For i = LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr1)
    Arr3(i) = Arr1(i, 1) + Arr2(i, 1)
Next
```

> ```
> Dim W1, W2, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5 As Double
> ```

In the declaration above `R5`'s datatype is Double the rest are Variants.

[image]

Here are a few videos that will help: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 3 - What to do When Things Go Wrong (Errors and Debugging)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=DlqKfYTgc9Q&index=3&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5), [Excel VBA Introduction Part 34 - Type Declarations (User-Defined Types)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=y9hnnfjTxUA&index=38&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) and [Excel VBA Introduction Part 25 - Arrays](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&index=28&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use explicit sheet name for Range references
2. You create a 2D array when reading a range into an array so use Transpose if planning on looping as shown as will generate a 1D array off the single column ranges being passed in
3. Declare and Redim Arr3 so enough space for all items

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    Dim Arr1(), Arr2(), Arr3(), i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Arr1 = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("M15:M30").Value)
    Arr2 = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("N15:N30").Value)
    ReDim Arr3(1 To UBound(Arr1))
    For i = LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr1)
        Arr3(i) = Arr1(i) + Arr2(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a 2D array

```
Public Sub TEST()    
    Dim Arr(), Arr3(), i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M15:N30") ' reference wanted range in wanted sheet and workbook
            Arr = .Value ' store referenced range values in an array
            ReDim Arr3(1 To UBound(Arr, 1))
            For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
                Arr3(i) = Arr(i, 1) + Arr(i, 2)
            Next
        .Offset(18).Resize(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr3) ' paste array values to referenced range offsetted 18 rows down and resize to one column
    End With
End Sub
```